# ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15

Tags: ffmpeg, libpng

ffmpeg is required for clipbucket

we have installed ffmpeg on server it do exist on path `/usr/bin/` but when type `ffmpeg -version` it gives strange error

*ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

the following is output of my terminal

```
alam@MYServer:~$ uname -a
Linux MYServer 3.13.0-100-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 18 16:48:51 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

alam@MYServer:~$ which ffmpeg
/usr/bin/ffmpeg

alam@MYServer:~$ cd /usr/bin

alam@MYServer:/usr/bin$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

alam@MYServer:/usr/bin$
```

Comment: Silly question: do you have libpng installed, and, if so, what version?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is this? Where did you get your `ffmpeg` package?

Comment: If libpng15-15 was ever in Ubuntu it would have been for a short time & never in 14.04 nor in any currently supported version. Did you get ffmpeg from some Debian repo?